# Can I include a custom payload or value with amazon affiliate links?

Tags: affiliate, amazon-product-api

I'd like to be able to tag affiliate links with some extra information so that I can map successes to information inside of my system.

Is there any way I can include a custom identifier or payload of data with the affiliate link that Amazon will allow me to inspect when I receive a report of successful sales?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I found is the tracking ids from
Manage Your Tracking IDs page.

However this ids are limited to 100 values by default (you need to contact amazon for more). This is what they answered me:

> I understand you'd like to view reporting within Products Advertising
>   API.
>
> All reports are housed on your Associates account for you to view the
>   activity of your links.
>
> We do offer multiple tracking IDs so that Associates can track the
>   activity of individual links easily and accurately.
>
> You can create up to 100 tracking IDs in your account by visiting the
>   Account Settings section of Associates Central. You'll find a link in
>   the Account Information section labeled Manage your tracking IDs:
>
> https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/network/your-account/manage-t...
>
> Once you've created your additional tracking IDs, to view these IDs,
>   please log into Associates Central (http://associates.amazon.com).
>   Once logged in, click on the drop down box under Tracking ID to change
>   which ID you are working with.
>
> If you are interested in receiving more than 100 tracking IDs, please
>   first create this amount via your associate account in Associate
>   Central. If you have already created 100 tracking IDs in your account
>   and are needing additional tracking IDs, please use the link below to
>   write back to us with a detailed description of how you'll be using
>   these additional ID: